# ROC curve for deep learning

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, keras, tensorflow

I am working in a deep learning project for image classification. I am using Vgg16 to create the model and the dataset has 100 classes. The testing accuracy is 98.9% and loss is 0.1731

And I got the following ROC and Average Precision curves: 
[image]
[image]

I do not now if the ROC and Average Precision result are good results or there is a problem in the curves because the curves are perfect. Do you know why I got ROC =1? Is there any problem in ROC and average precision?

Comment: Is it on train or test dataset?

Comment: This result on the test dataset

Comment: I would recommend to check it manually that the results are that good. Choose one picture run the algorithm and see the result. Otherwise I would just say Wow! This kind of precision I can only dream about. I have never ever seen something that good.

Comment: It's not possible to have it as 1

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically, it is not possible to have the area under the curve equal to 1 if you have a precision less than 1... If you have a doubt, you should check the confusion matrix and calcuate the scores yourself. You'll know directly if you did a mistake or not

A few other remarks:

- Accuracy is not precision
- The loss is of no help here